# Using etc/security/time.conf for groups

Tags: command-line, login, pam

how could I set for group "spedytorzy" logon hours 7-15 from Monday to Friday?
Actually I have *;*;@spedytorzy;Wk0700-1500 and added to /etc/pam.d/sshd file ,,account required pam_exec.so". I add that I have an one account added to time.conf, and I want to make it without scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `%` symbol instead for normal groups. The `@` symbol is for netgroups. You would replace the line in your `/etc/security/time.conf` file with the following:

```
*;*;%spedytorzy;Wk0700-1500
```

Now this login (actually `*` = all security actions) policy will apply to everyone in the spedytorzy group. You don't need to use scripts to modify the `time.conf` any more after editing this; you only need to add them to the group.

Regarding your edit to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`, that is not the best way to do things. The best way is to edit `/etc/pam.d/login` and uncomment the `# account    requisite  pam_time.so` line.

Comment: still not working, for exact accounts it's working, but for users with group "spedytorzy" it's not. I did what you said with /etc/pam.d/login